# How to make this SQL query into DotNet Core 2.1 Linq

Tags: linq, t-sql, .net-core

Here's the T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    'Total Tournaments' AS Name, COUNT(a.location) AS Value
FROM
    (SELECT location
     FROM [dbo].[TournamentBatchItem]
     GROUP BY TournamentName, location) a

UNION

SELECT 
    'Outdoor Tournaments' AS Name, COUNT(a.location) AS Value
FROM
    (SELECT location
     FROM [dbo].[TournamentBatchItem]
     GROUP BY TournamentName, location) a
WHERE a.location = 'Outdoor'

UNION

SELECT 
    'Indoor Tournaments' AS Name, COUNT(a.location) AS Value
FROM
    (SELECT location
     FROM [dbo].[TournamentBatchItem]
     GROUP BY TournamentName, location) a
WHERE a.location = 'Indoor'
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Name                | Value
--------------------+-------
Indoor Tournaments  |   0
Outdoor Tournaments |   1
TotalTournaments    |   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with one single trip to the database :

```
var tournaments = _db.TournamentBatchItems
                  // Where clause is optional, needed only if you have others locations than indoor and outdoor 
                 .Where(t => t.Location == "Outdoor" || t.Location == "Indoor")
                 .GroupBy(t => t.Location)
                 .Select(t => new { Name = $"{ t.Key } Tournaments", Value = t.Count()})
                 .ToList();

tournaments.Add(new { Name = "Total Tournaments", Value = tournaments.Sum(t => t.Value)});
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic one would be like this:

```
var totalTournaments = (from tbi from _db.TournamentBatchItems select tbi.location).Count();
var whatever = (from tbi from _db.TournamentBatchItems where something==something select tbi.location).Count();
```

Then build the list manually with text strings "Total Tournaments". (Or use the union command), but my advice is only to ask for count and nothing else in the query.